# Why flutter give an error 'Undefined name DateFormat"?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, flutter-intl

How can I fix it? Please don't say import intl.dart as you can see at the second photo I already add it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be using the Date Format class from another package.

-> import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;

Edit the import like this.

Try using the date format as below.

intl.DateFormat.yMMMd().format(transaction[index].date),

Answer (score 4):

Your import statement has a red line under it. Meaning it has an error. Most likely you didn't include `intl` in your dependencies. You need to add this in the dependencies section of your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
intl: ^0.17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal in VSCode (Ctrl + Shift + ') then type `flutter pub add intl` to add the intl package on your dependencies.